# Overlap coefficient for two multidimensional normal distributions

Tags: r, distributions, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

For two PDFs $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ the overlap coefficient (OVL) measures the similarity between two distributions through the overlapping area of their distribution functions and is given by the formula
$$
OVL = \int \min[f_1(x), f_2(x)]dx.
$$
This is a univariate case. For the bivariate case and $f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)$ it could be probably generalized to
$$
MVOVL = \int\int \min[f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)]dxdy.
$$

In this case we focus on gaussian MVN. **How to compute MVOVL** in R? I could obviously integrate over $\mathbb R^2$, but I need to know when $f_1(x,y) \leq f_2(x,y)$, so
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi|\Sigma_1|}}\cdot \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\mu_1)\} &\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi|\Sigma_2|}}\cdot \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2)\} \ || \cdot |\Sigma_1||\Sigma_2|\\
    |\Sigma_2|^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\mu_1)\} &\leq |\Sigma_2|^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2)\} \ || \ln()\\
    {\frac{1}{2}}\ln|\Sigma_2|- \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\mu_1) &\leq {\frac{1}{2}}\ln|\Sigma_2| -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2) \ || \ \cdot (-2))\\
    \ln|\Sigma_2|- (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\mu_1) &\leq \ln|\Sigma_2| -(x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2)\\
   \ln\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|}- (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(x-\mu_1) +(x-\mu_2)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(x-\mu_2) &\leq 0
\end{align}
But my calculations lead me nowhere, as there are two quadratic forms. Have you got any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: This is not an easy integral to compute because its calculation amounts to (1) finding the locus of points where $\log f_1(x,y) = \log f_2(x,y)$ and (2) performing separate integrations inside and outside this ellipse.  Perhaps this is one of the reasons such a metric is rarely used... .

Comment: @whuber fair point. are there any good measures except for Kullback–Leibler divergence and Bhattacharyya distance that you know about?

Comment: There are a great many: you can use any common metric based on the CDF, PDF, characteristic function, etc.